# MDX get DISTINCT COUNT for Month to Date

Tags: reporting-services, distinct, mdx, olap

**EXPLANATION**

We have OLAP cube, there is Measure *Customer Count* which is `DistinctCount` of *CustomerId*.

Now we created SSRS report that using previously mentioned cube as data source. In the report we calculating Month to Date data.

**EXAMPLE**

If we use filter in SSRS report *2023-12-04*, we should get data of the following days: `12-01, 12-02, 12-03`

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Date         Distinct Customer Count
2023-12-01   125
2023-12-02   110
2023-12-03   115
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

Month to Date Customer Count = 172 (this is just for sample purpose, unique customers count)

But if we're using `SUM([Month to Date],[Measures].[Online Player Count])` we get 350 (sum of 3 records) what is incorrect, because the same customers could visit all 3 days (2nd visit in period shouldn't be counted).

If we using `COUNT()` instead of `SUM()`, we get Month to Date Customer Count = 3 (num of days filtered)

We need to get Customers Distinct Count of Month to Date period.

**WHAT WE TRIED**

```
IIF([Date].[Date].currentmember is [Date].[Date].[Mtd],SUM([Month to Date],[Measures].[Customer Count]))
```

In cube we also have Customers dimension with *CustomerId* attribute, so we tried to use in SSRS's MDX:

```
IIF(... COUNT(EXISTING [Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members))
IIF(... COUNT(DISTINCT [Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members))
```

But those not working, it returning the same Count for any day filtered.

Have you ideas how to achieve it?

**UPDATE**

More info:

In `Dataset properties` > `Parameters` I have declared Parameter *Mtd* with following expression:

```
="([Date].[Date].&["
+FORMAT(DateSerial(Year(Parameters!Date.Value), Month(Parameters!Date.Value), 1),"yyyyMMdd") 
+ "]:[Date].[Date].&[" + FORMAT(CDATE(Parameters!Date.Value),"yyyyMMdd") + "])"
```

And in MDX query I set `Month to Date` in following:

```
set [Month to Date] as STRTOSet(@Mtd)
```

`Month to Date` working as expected with other data like `Spent Amount`, `Balance` and etc. Problem occurs only with `Distinct Customer Count`

**UPDATE #2**

If we're using following *CustomerCount* logic as @VonC suggested, we get the same number on *Month to Date* as on `Year to Date` and it not change after we trying to select different date filter.

Maybe with this `SELECT ( FILTER () )` logic Distinct count of Customers should be calculated in other way?

```
MEMBER [Measures].[CustomerCountPerDays] AS DISTINCTCOUNT([Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members) 

MEMBER [Measures].[CustomerCount] AS SUM( [Month to Date], [Measures].[CustomerCountPerDays] )


SELECT {[Measures].[Bets], [GGR], [Change (GGR)], [Measures].[CustomerCount]} on columns,
{[Date].[Date].[MTD],[Date].[Date].[YTD]} ON ROWS
FROM (
SELECT ( FILTER( 
         [Partner].[Partner].[Partner].ALLMEMBERS
       , [Partner].[Partner].currentmember.Properties('Member_Caption')="OurParner" )) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [OurCube])
```

*NOTE: Bets, GGR, etc. shows correct data for MTD and YTD*

Comment: Would [`Exist`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/exists-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`DistinctCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/distinctcount-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16) help? As in `MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueCustomerMtdCount] AS DISTINCTCOUNT( EXISTS( [Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members, [SelectedMonthToDate] ) )`

Comment: @VonC thank you for your answer. If I'm using following: `MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueCustomerMtdCount] AS DISTINCTCOUNT( EXISTS( [Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members, [Month to Date] ) )` I'm getting `NULL`. To be clear - I've replaced `[SelectedMonthToDate]` with `[Month to Date]`

Comment: But: if `[Month to Date]` is not properly defined as a set of dates, or does not align with the `[Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members` set, the `EXISTS` function might not work as expected. Make sure `[Month to Date]` is a set of dates that correctly represents the desired month-to-date range. It should be aligned with your date dimension in the cube.

Comment: If it is aligned, then try `WITH MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueCustomerMtdCount] AS DISTINCTCOUNT( EXISTS( [Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members, [Month to Date], "Measures.[Customer Count]" ) ) SELECT [Measures].[UniqueCustomerMtdCount] ON COLUMNS FROM  [YourCube] WHERE  ([Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[2023-12-04])`

Comment: @VonC thanks for your answers. I've updated my question with additional information in  **UPDATE** section. `Month to Date` is declared in Dataset Parameters, it working with other facts, except with `Customer Count`.  Still getting *NULL*.

Comment: Maybe distinct counts require special handling in MDX, especially when dealing with sets and across time dimensions. Instead of using the `EXISTS` function, you could try to directly use the `[Month to Date]` set within a `SUM` function, combined with a calculated member that counts distinct customers per day.

Comment: `mdx WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CustomerCountPerDay] AS DISTINCTCOUNT([Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members) MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueCustomerMtdCount] AS SUM( [Month to Date], [Measures].[CustomerCountPerDay] ) SET [Month to Date] AS STRTOSET(@Mtd) SELECT [Measures].[UniqueCustomerMtdCount] ON COLUMNS FROM [YourCube]`

Comment: @VonC thank you one more time, but still this not working as expected. With logic that you suggested above MTD and YTD numbers are the same and doesn't matter what date we pick, always shows the same result for Month to Date. Updated my question with more details, check **UPDATE #2** section, please.

Comment: Instead of calculating the distinct count of customers for each day and then summing it up, which leads to incorrect aggregation, you would need to scope the distinct count directly to the MTD and YTD sets. How about using a subselects to create a filtered context for the query, i.e. to make sure the distinct count is calculated within the context of the filtered set (MTD or YTD)? Using `(SELECT [Month to Date] FROM [YourCube])` and `(SELECT [Year to Date] FROM [YourCube])`.

Comment: @VonC this time I misunderstood idea how code should look like. To be clear, I don't have attribute `Month to Date` in cube, as described in the question,  I'm declaring it in Query Designer in following: `set [Month to Date] as STRTOSet(@Mtd)` where `@mtd` is Parameter declared in following: `="([Date].[Date].&["
+FORMAT(DateSerial(Year(Parameters!Date.Value), Month(Parameters!Date.Value), 1),"yyyyMMdd") 
+ "]:[Date].[Date].&[" + FORMAT(CDATE(Parameters!Date.Value),"yyyyMMdd") + "])"`  So I don't have idea how to use `(SELECT [Month to Date] FROM [YourCube])` properly.

Comment: OK. Since `[Month to Date]` is not a predefined attribute in the cube but rather a set dynamically defined in the Query Designer based on a parameter, you could directly use the `@Mtd` parameter within your MDX query to define the `Month to Date` context. `@Mtd` is a string representation of the date range, so `STRTOSET` is used to convert it into a set that MDX can understand. That set will then be used in a subselect to create the desired context for the calculation of distinct counts.

Comment: Something like: `WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[MTDCustomerCount] AS  DISTINCTCOUNT( EXISTING [Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members )
SELECT  {[Measures].[Bets], [Measures].[GGR], [Measures].[Change (GGR)], [Measures].[MTDCustomerCount]} ON COLUMNS, {[Date].[Date].[MTD], [Date].[Date].[YTD]} ON ROWS
FROM  ( SELECT STRTOSET(@Mtd, CONSTRAINED) ON COLUMNS  FROM [YourCube] )`

Comment: @VonC I'm not sure if I'm using `STRTOSET(@Mtd, CONSTRAINED)` correctly, It returning `NULL`. I'm trying to use: `MEMBER [Measures].[MTDCustomerCount] AS  DISTINCTCOUNT( EXISTING [Customers].[CustomerId].[CustomerId].Members )

SELECT {[Measures].[Bets],[Stakes],[GGR], [Measures].[MTDCustomerCount]} on columns,
{[Date].[Date].[MTD],[Date].[Date].[YTD]} on rows
FROM (
select ( Filter( 
[Partner].[Partner].[Partner].ALLMEMBERS
, [Partner].[Partner].currentmember.Properties('Member_Caption')="OurParner" )
, STRTOSET(@Mtd, CONSTRAINED)) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [OurCube])`